# Select through check box and change the value from Radio button in table

Tags: javascript, php

i am new to php, i need help

i have table in Mysql as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOEFz.png)

and above the table i have three radio button

```
<div>
    
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check">Active</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check">Inactive</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check">Closed</label>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lCsK.png)

now what i have to do, i will select any one/muyltiple entry from table through check box and click on any of radio button (here selecting Active) so the value in Status column change to Active in data base and display here also.
i need that codes, please help me.

Comment: You need some client-side scripting for that - try to google AJAX in Javascript. You need send your data (row id and status) to the backend (PHP) script, that will update relevant row.

Comment: This is not a site where you can simply ask people to write your code for you. I suggest you find a beginner's PHP tutorial, which will explain how HTML forms work, and how to process them in PHP. Then have a go, and if you have a *specific* problem, post it here, making sure to read [ask] first.

Comment: @PavelTřupek This is all perfectly possible without client-side code: all the tick-boxes can be part of one form, and the PHP can see which ones were checked, update them, and re-render the page. AJAX would be a nice next step, but I would suggest not to run before you can walk.

Comment: @IMSoP I was just answering the question - how to do after checking radio button

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value="Active" value="Inactive" value="Closed" in the button then try to submit.